# Remove images appearing on the aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created some ImageButtons in code-behind.
Then, populated a list of ImageButtons as:

```
    protected void Image_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton imgButton = sender as ImageButton;
        imgButton.ImageUrl = Resource.TICK_IMAGE; 

        // some work

        ImageButtonList.Add(imgButton);
    }
```

On my ASPX page some images will appear now.
After some time, I want to remove those images.

I tried something like:

```
buttonList.Clear();
```

But, still the images are appearing on the ASPX page. How should I remove those images?

My whole code looks like:

```
public static List<Image> RandomImages = new List<Image>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonList.Clear();

      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form[Resource.RESET_BUTTON_ID]) || !Page.IsPostBack)
      {
          RandomImages = ResetGame();
      }
      AddCardsToDisplay(RandomImages, CardDiv, true);
}

public void AddCardsToDisplay(List<Image> Images, System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl DivisionName, bool isClickable)
{
    foreach (var image in Images)
    {
        ImageButton button = Utilities.CreateImageButton(image.NewImageURL, image.ID, CardDiv);
        AddImageButtonClickEvent(button, isClickable);
    }
}


protected List<Image> ResetGame()
{
    NumberOfClicks = 0;
    return GetRandomImages(NUMBER_OF_IMAGES);
}

    public static ImageButton CreateImageButton(string imageUrl, string id, System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl DivisionName)
    {
        ImageButton button = new ImageButton { ImageUrl = imageUrl, ID = id };
        DivisionName.Controls.Add(button);
        return button;
    }
```

Comment: `imgbtn` is an ImageButton object and not a image button itself.

Comment: So, how should I remove them?

Comment: Instead of "After sometime", can you explain on what event are you trying to clear the list?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the command "Clear" from your list. To empty the usages pf those buttons. Do that instead of your foreach loop

```
 ImageButtonList.Clear();
```

And it should work. :-)

**EDIT**

I thought that the imagelist was the parent of those controls. But it does not seem to be the case.

If you want to remove the button itself, try do something as:

```
 imgButton.Parent.Controls.Remove(imgButton);
```

If you want to just hide them. Then do

```
 imgButton.Visible = false;
```

Last but not least. You can reset the image url, set it to null. And it shouldmt be visible (not sure if it will give you a red x though)

Comment: haha... I know that, but my issue is that, once the image is clicked, its imageUrl is set to TICK_IMAGE. Even after doing ImageButtonList.Clear(), the TICK_IMAGE still appears at that place.